# Are programming career-related question allowed on SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

Am I allowed to ask questions related to "what can I do with this knowledge for" theme on Stack Overflow? Of course, in the topic of programming.

Comment: no, that is off-topic.

Comment: Ofcourse, I' talking about programming knowledge. Forgot to make it obvious, sorry.

Comment: Still off-topic.

Comment: Sadly I can't ask on Pogrammers because of downvoting. Thanks for answering anyway!

Comment: Career questions are also off topic on programmers. There's even a special close reason for them

Comment: But then, *where to ask* about career-related questions? May it be worth a new prposal if there isn't yet?

Comment: Ask a career counselor. Stack Exchange is not a place for career advice.

Comment: If you're looking for someone's opinion on your career options I'd personally go to reddit

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I think I can ask something in this theme that would be useful even for someone else. And this is one of the main purposes of SE, isn't it?

Comment: SE never set out to be a jack of all trades. It has a clear mission and does not deviate from it

Comment: @RichardTingle I can't see the deviation in it.

Comment: I'm saying that just because something may be "useful even for someone else" doesn't mean it belongs on SE

Comment: @RichardTingle Oh well...that's right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions related to career advice would mostly solicit opinion-based answers which do not fit in the Stack Exchange model of Q&A.

Also, such question may not help future visitors either. Some related discussion on [Are Career Advice questions useful to anyone except the poster?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/are-career-advice-questions-useful-to-anyone-except-the-poster)

Comment: Seems legit. THanks for linking that question!

Answer (score 2):

Questions related to programming are welcome here! Anything that you are trying, and is not working would have an answer here.

But this community (Stackoverflow) has some rules. Which are fairly described on the about page as:

[image]

So, you will not ask for **recommendations** or you will not start any poll or ask for opinions. As far as discussion is related, you can start a long discussion in Chat rooms here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/. This chat site is designed for programmers who want to discuss about **what this code works and how**.

Secondly, your question

> "what can I do with this knowledge for"

Contains a poll or opinion type thing. You can ask for a code, if you have a piece of code you can ask what can I do to make this code work, but not to ask for something like, I have an idea on my mind, what code can do this job.

To ask questions that are opinion based, or when you need some help from others or when you want a suggestion you can always go to [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). This is the site, where you can ask questions which have anything related to suggestions or asking for what method would be best to do this!

Good luck! Cheers.